# What was the first LISP not created by John McCarthy?

Tags: programming-languages, lisp, history

Please correct me if I am wrong but I understand that John McCarthy was involved with first versions of LISP, but variations of the language were created starting with 1.5.

My question is what was the first non-McCarthy version of LISP?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, technically, McCarthy didn't actually create LISP, the way we know it.  McCarthy created a formalism for reasoning about programs, that looked a fair amount like LISP, but not exactly.  Steve "Slug" Russell realized that it would not be difficult to implement that formalism in a computer program on the IBM 704, and did so.

It was a bug in that original program that gave us the traditional formatting of LISP lists.  The code was supposed to display

> (A, B, C)

and a bug caused it to display

> (A B C)

instead.  Everyone who saw it liked the comma-less form better, and the bug became a feature.

The names CAR and CDR came directly from the IBM 704 architecture.